# Ubuntu on old MacBook Pro not responding to input after boot

Tags: boot, grub2, macbook-pro, input

My computer, a *circa* 2014 MacBook Pro Model A1502 running Ubuntu, has stopped responding to input after boot. I can uuse the keyboard to control GRUB, but as soon as I leave grub, my computer stops responding to all input. *Nothing* works, not the trackpad, not the keyboard, not a USB mouse, not a USB keyboard, not a Bamboo Pen and Touch. I press the caps lock key, and it doesn't light up. The only thing that does work is the power button.

Some help articles I read suggested it might be a driver problem with X and recommended that I boot into single-user mode. I did that, but again, everything stopped working as soon as I left GRUB. This happens no matter which of the available versions of the kernel (which, according to GRUB, are 5.11.0-46, 5.11.0-44, 5.11.0-41) I boot into.

I had a similar problem with this computer a while back where the computer would become unresponsive after booting up or after restoring from sleep mode—and, seemingly, during use whenever a USB input devices got unplugged—but a reboot or two usually solved the issue. This time, that's not working.

My GRUB version is 2.04. I *believe* Ubuntu version is 20.04 LTS, but I can't check (unless there is some way to do so from GRUB that I don't know about).

Can anyone tell me what the problem mmight be and how it might be solved?

Comment: Can you SSH into the machine after it boots? If so, you may be able to resolve the issue by installing an input package: `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-all`

Comment: @matigo: I couldn't SSH in, so I booted from a live USB and chrooted into my main filesystem to do that, but it told me that that `xserver-xorg-input-all` was already installed.